I can't add fingerprint on macos
We have both Windows and MacBook devices in our company. Since it's a domain environment, we added the MacBook devices to the domain as well, but the performance was not satisfactory. Therefore, I’m reverting them back to local. Here’s how I handled it initially:
During the setup, I first created a local user. After adding the device to the domain, I logged in with the domain user and set up the account as a portable account. I also gave the user administrative privileges.
To revert it back to local, I deleted the portable user but kept the home folder. I removed the device from the domain. Then, I created a local administrator user with the same name as the home folder. The original local user created during the first setup still exists. When I logged in with the local user, everything was intact and functional. However, it doesn't allow us to set up fingerprints. I think I need to assign permissions on the volume because the original setup user is allowed to add fingerprints.
What steps should I follow to resolve this?

If you create a new local user are you able to add fingerprints?

As I said, it does not let the local user I opened do it. I was running the code below while the device was in the domain.
/usr/sbin/sysadminctl -secureTokenOn user.name  -password user_pass -adminUser admin_user -adminPassword -

I am asking you to create a new local user.  I am trying to rule out if there is a permission problem with the user you created or if the problem is something else. Creating a test user will eliminate a few possible explanations.

Can you update your Question to be specific about the user ID numbers involved? Like, was the first local user UID# 501? Was the portable domain user UID# 502? Is the new local user with the same name as the previous portable domain user UID# 503? What UID# owns the files in the preserved home directory?
